# Is there a way to override bundle DI extension file in Symfony?

Tags: symfony

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to override the DI extension file in Sf2.

The reason I want to override this file is that I'm using a 3rd party bundle where they define certain services, check for certain params in this file. However, since I want to customize these settings and store them in a different way I need a way to either override or skip the loading of this file.

I have searched high

Comment: You can create compiler passes that modify the container as you desire before it is dumped (see, for example, http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html#creating-separate-compiler-passes and http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html).

Comment: Thank you, I figured out after reading the source code that currently there seems to be no way to directly override the extension file, so your method seems to be the best option for now.